# Why is the console claiming that the array is undefined?

Tags: javascript

When i run the first of the following code variants, the console prints the array as expected. But when I run the second variant, the console claims the array to be undefined. Could anybody please explain why?

```
function tipCalculator(bill){
    var parcentage;

if (bill < 50){
    parcentage = .2;
}else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
    parcentage = .15;
}else{
    parcentage = .1;
}
return parcentage * bill;
};


var bills = [124 , 48, 205];
var tips = [tipCalculator(bills[0]), 
        tipCalculator(bills[1]),
        tipCalculator(bills[2])];

console.log(tips)
```

---

```
function tipCalculator (bill){


    var twentyPercent = bill * 0.2;
    var fifteenyPercent = bill * 0.15;
  var tenPercent = bill * 0.1;

if (bill < 50 ) {
    console.log ('Waiter will get 20% of the bill which is ' + 
twentyPercent);
} else if ( bill >= 50 && bill < 201) {
    console.log( 'Waiter will get 15% of the bill which is ' + 
fifteenyPercent);
} else if ( bill > 200) {
    console.log(' Waiter will get 10% of the  bill which is ' + tenPercent);
} else{
    console.log('Waiter won\'t get any tip' );
}

};

var bills = [124 , 48, 205];
var tips = [tipCalculator(bills[0]), 
        tipCalculator(bills[1]),
        tipCalculator(bills[2])];

console.log(tips)
```

Comment: `tipCalculator` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to return something:

```
 function tipCalculator(bill) {
  var twentyPercent = bill * 0.2;
  var fifteenPercent = bill * 0.15;
  var tenPercent = bill * 0.1;

  if (bill < 50) {
    console.log("Waiter will get 20% of the bill which is " + twentyPercent);
    return twentyPercent;
  } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 201) {
    console.log("Waiter will get 15% of the bill which is " + fifteenPercent);
    return fifteenPercent;
  } else if (bill > 200) {
    console.log(" Waiter will get 10% of the  bill which is " + tenPercent);
    return tenPercent;
  }
}

var bills = [124, 48, 205];
var tips = [
  tipCalculator(bills[0]),
  tipCalculator(bills[1]),
  tipCalculator(bills[2])
];

console.log(tips);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second code your tipCalculator function is missing a return statement, thus the tips array is not being populated properly.

Comment: why do i need a return function? 
What should i return , can you please explain?

Comment: In the second example you are printing to the console an array that gets its values from a function that doesn't return a value - thus the array has 3 undefined values.

Comment: zhulkov 
thanks a lot.... thank you so much. 
got it. u r a genius